# Why are the terms electrophile/nucleophile used? Are they not identical to Lewis acids/bases?

Tags: chemistry

My understanding is that the above pairs of terms are identical in definition, indicating acceptors/donors of an electron pair. So, why are both used?

Comment: "*To avoid confusion between the Lewis and the Bronsted definitions of acids and bases, Lewis bases are sometimes called nucleophiles, and Lewis acids are called electrophiles*", [Cortes, Organic Chemistry notes](https://www.utdallas.edu/~scortes/ochem/OChem1_Lecture/Class_Materials/12_lewis_ac_bases.pdf). Some information on the origins of Lewis's and Bronsted-Lowry's theories (both came out in 1923) and their differences is given in the [Wikipedia's history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases#History).

Comment: Just like all apples are fruits but not all fruits are apples, all electrophiles are Lewis acids, but not all Lewis acids are electrophiles. Hence the need of separate terms. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21623/why-cant-all-electrophiles-act-as-lewis-acids